# Configuration Error on IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have uploaded my C# webservice in IIS in my server. When i browse the service, i get the below error.

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your  configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel.

Source Error: 


Line 105:    </runtime>
Line 106:
Line 107:    <system.serviceModel>
Line 108:        <bindings>
Line 109:            <basicHttpBinding>


Source File: E:\xxxx03102014\GoTV\abcderfcvngh\web.config    Line: 107
```

Comment: What version is your IIS and the targeted .Net Framework version of your webservice?

Answer (score 1):

It sound to me like the service is running IIS 2.0 or below

system.service Model is only available in 3.0 and up.

Try checking what application pool is running in IIS on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the .NET version from 3.0 to up in the the pool of the IIS.